# Unable to mute video element with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, video, mute

```
let muteBtn = document.querySelector('#mute');
muteBtn.addEventListener('click',muteVideo);
function muteVideo(){
    if (this.getAttribute('src') == "mute.png") {
        video.muted() == false;
        this.setAttribute('src', 'mute.png');
    } else {
        video.muted() == true;
        this.setAttribute('src', 'mute.png');
    }
}
```

> Javascript code for muting video. Can't make it work

Comment: You don't mute video. You mute audio. ;)

Comment: @ScottMarcus - I was about to say the same..  cool

Comment: can you provide more code, including the <video> tag?

Comment: `.muted` is a property, not a method. `vdeo.muted = false | true)`. Also, you use a single `=` to assign a value, not `==`. See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/muted).

Comment: @ScottMarcus `<video src="video.mp4"></video>
  <div class="btnHolder"><img id="play" src="play.png">
   <img id="reload" src="reload.png">
   <img id="mute" src="mute.png">`

Comment: @Migoda Not sure what you want me to see with that added HTML. Doesn't change the problem or the solution.

Comment: @ScottMarcus well, you asked for more code, <video> tag

Comment: @Migoda Actually, I didn't. That was Jannik. But, even when you do decide to add more code, please don't add it as a comment. Edit your question and add it there.

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues:

1. `.muted` is a property, not a method. There should not be `()` after
   the property name.
2. Also, you use a single `=` to assign a value, not `==`.

==========

```
video.muted = false;
video.muted = true;
```

See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/muted).

Now, as an aside, if you are getting an element by its `id`, the fastest DOM query for that is `.getElementById()`, not `querySelector()`. Also, you can change the current state of the DOM object by accessing its object properties, rather than its HTML attribute. So, the final code is:

```
let muteBtn = document.getElementById('mute');

muteBtn.addEventListener('click',muteVideo);

function muteVideo(){
    if (this.src == "mute.png") {
        video.muted = false;
        this.src = 'unmute.png';
    } else {
        video.muted = true;
        this.src = 'mute.png;
    }
}
```

Having said all of that, it would be much simpler to just set `muted` to the opposite of what it currently is and then set the image based on the current `muted` value:

```
document.getElementById('mute').addEventListener('click', function(){
    video.muted = !video.muted; // Switch mute to the opposite of what it is

    // Use a ternary "if" condition to set the image one way or the other:
    this.src = (video.muted) ? "mute.jpg" : "unmute.jpg";
}
```

Comment: used `querySelector()` cause it was in YT tutorial

Comment: @Migoda Understood. Just remember that not all code that "works" is good code. ;)

Comment: why did the YT guy use `querySelector`?

Comment: @Migoda Because he didn't know the difference. There are always more than one way to do something and often it doesn't matter which you choose. `.querySelector()` is fine, but `.getElementById()` is better/faster He probably didn't know that.

Comment: figured out how to mute and unmute `function muteVideo(){
 if (this.getAttribute('src') == "mute.png") {
  video.muted = true;
  this.setAttribute('src', 'sound-off.png');
 } else {
  video.muted = false;
  this.setAttribute('src', 'mute.png');
 }
}`  :)))

Comment: @Migoda Not sure why you say you figured it out when I posted this same answer 2 days ago. As I said `this.setAttribute("src", "sound-off.png")` can be written simply as `this.src = "sound-off.jpg"`. Same idea for `.getAttribute`.